# Gradle Zip Task: Add Dynamically Generated File

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle build script in which I'm using the 'Zip' task to generate a zip archive directly from a source directory.

In addition to copying over all the files inside the source directory structure into the zip archive, I'm looking for a way to include a dynamically generated file that's not in the source directory.

Do you guys know how I can do this?

Here's pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
task('archive', type: Zip) {
  ...
  from 'source'
  newFile('dynamically-generated.txt', 'dynamic file content')
}
```

And here are the source and destination structures:

```
[i71178@bddev01-shell01 ~]$ tree source/
source/
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
└── file3.txt

0 directories, 3 files
[i71178@bddev01-shell01 ~]$ unzip -l destination.zip
Archive:  destination.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name

---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  02-26-2016 16:56   source/
        0  02-26-2016 16:56   source/file2.txt
        0  02-26-2016 16:56   source/dynamically-generated.txt
        0  02-26-2016 16:56   source/file1.txt
        0  02-26-2016 16:56   source/file3.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     5 files
```

Comment: *include a dynamically generated file that's not in the source directory* Then where is it?

Comment: The content will be generated dynamically (via code) at build/copy time and I want a new file created in the destination zip archive with a supplied name and content.

Comment: How is it any different from `from 'source'` then? Just add another `from` line with the new directory.

Comment: So, this file doesn't exist in the source. As I'm copying files over from 'source' to 'destination', I also want to insert a new file in the 'destination' that has some content that's generated on the fly.

I'll update the question to make that clear.

Comment: create the file in a different task. You can force that task to run before zip task using `dependsOn`

Comment: So, I'm trying to avoid involving a 'Copy' task in the middle to put the source files into a 'destination-dir' and then Zip the files in the 'destination-dir' into 'destination.zip'. If I do that, yes, I can create a file in the 'destination-dir' before I run the 'Zip' task and as a matter of fact, that is what I'm doing right now. I'm just trying to do away with the useless 'destination-dir' I create.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot extend a zip task to do some other intermediate steps.

Comment: Doesn't still solve your tempdir problem, but you may be able to do it in one task like this: https://gist.github.com/foragerr/e74a3de1e88d7265fc37

Comment: Cool! I'll try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'myPlugin'

  //The 'build' task is set up by the plugin
  build {
    //Customization to keep consistent with artifacts being currently generated.
    doFirst {
      new File(getTemporaryDir(), 'artifact-fullname.txt').text = "${project.name}-${project.version}\n"
    }
    archiveName = "${project.name}.${project.build.extension}"
    from getTemporaryDir()
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Combining my comments above and your getTemporaryDir comment:

```
task generateThenZip()<<{
    def tempDir = getTemporaryDir()
    newFile("$tempDir/dynamically-generated.txt", 'dynamic file content')

    zip{
        from 'source'
        from tempDir
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#getTemporaryDir()

I can create it there and the just do a from 'mytempfile'...

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to achieve it quite easyly on **Gradle 6.6.1**
by just creating the file in the `from` section.

```
distributions {
  main {
    contents {
      into("/") {
        from {
          if (!buildDir.exists()) {
            buildDir.mkdir()
          }
          def f = new File("$buildDir/all")
          f.text = "project_version: ${project.version}\n"
          f
        }
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

btw. I think `$buildDir` is safer than `/tmp`